# Merge two lists from diferent subsites using workflow

Tags: list, workflow

We have two lists from separate subsites, we need a third list on the main site that receive the items from both this lists. I tried to use Create list item with Sharepoint designer workflow, but it doesn't show any option to create a list item on the main site.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Call HTTP Web Service action (REST API calls) to implement your logic. It is complex thing, but it is solution.
You cannot get access from subsite to site by action used by you or by other out-of-box actions. My opinion - only Call HTTP Web Service action can help you.
Here you can find good guide about your issue solution:
http://blog.portiva.nl/2016/11/03/sharepoint-designer-call-http-web-service-to-create-item-in-other-site-collection/

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried to create a web part based on the list I wanted to show, but for some reason the workflow status (which is what we actually need) doesn't show up. The lists don't need to be merged, just need to be shown on the same page to avoid accessing more than one list at once.

Comment: What is it workflow status for you ? You have some custom workflow on each list in your two subsites and want to show status of that workflows on some page in root site colleciton ?

Comment: If yes and if by some reasons field with workflow status from your sub sites lists not accessible then you can try some workarounds. Your custom workflow can set its workflow status in custom field of same list item. =) If workflow by some reasons not started successfully or has error then custom field will be empty or with previous step status.

Comment: I haven't thought that... Thank you! But will I be able to click on in and go to the workflow status/logs?

Comment: You can set field type as hyperlink and build your own link same as current field have. Open list view with your current workflow status column, copy link from this column. I think it must be some general URL with parameters. I think you can get this parameters inside your workflow and build working link.